MS Excel: manually inserted data sticking to dynamic data
Is there a way to have dynamic data along with manual data so that the manual input sticks / stays in the same row with the external input even after the source changes?
In other words,

Have a source data in sheet1;
Make some kind of dynamic mirror of the data in sheet2, e.g. a pivot table or plain formula "=cell_in_sheet1";
Have some extra columns to the mirrored data in sheet2;
Input manually data to new columns in sheet2;
Insert a new row in between source data in sheet1;
See that the mirrored data in sheet2 (e.g. pivot) refreshes;
And the crucial point: Have the manual data stay with the same data it described before the row insertion.

Is it possible? If only with certain mirroring methods, which ones?
Basic visualization (numbers denote the sheets):
Before insert:



Source data (1)
Mirror data (2)
Manual data (2)




dog
dog
brown


cat
cat
black



After insert:



Source data (1)
Mirror data (2)
Manual data (2)




dog
dog
brown


fish
fish



cat
cat
black




When I edit the question, the tables are properly formatted, but here I see a mess. What am I doing wrong?

You need a carriage return before each table.

Thanks for your help!

It's certainly possible, but not trivial. One option would be: write a VBA subroutine, triggered by changes in the 'manual' column, which builds and maintains a (hidden) table of source+manual data, and replaces the manual data with an xlookup into that table.

For regular data, you can group worksheets.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/group-worksheets-4e1f7747-3d63-4fd7-8a36-838b05adc0f0
I haven't tried with pivot tables.
